# Renomear Database toda MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber se é possível renomear uma database toda do MySQL

Tenho a Database Cadastro com a tabela pessoas

Gostaria de renomear cadastro para CAD_CRS

É possível?

Comment: https://pt.blog.marceloaltmann.com/how-to-rename-a-database-in-mysql/

Comment: Não esqueça de efetuar um backup completo de seu site (pasta do site + banco de dados).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin tem uma operação para isso.

No PhpMyAdmin, selecione o banco de dados que deseja renomear. Nas guias, há uma chamada Operações, após isso, vá para a seção de renomeação.

[image: Renomear DB]

Ou, crie um novo banco de dados com o novo nome, despeje todas as tabelas do banco de dados antigo no novo banco de dados e apague o banco de dados antigo.